# React: Have to constantly update state to make textarea editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

In my component, I render this textarea:

```
<textarea id="descript" rows="8" value={this.state.description} />
```

and I was surprised to find that I couldn't type in it. After some experimentation, I found that I was typing it in, but react was just reseting the value every time I typed a character to the state variable. So, I've gotten it to let me type by adding this onChange:

```
<textarea id="descript" rows="8" value={this.state.description} 
  onChange={() => {this.textChanged();}} />
```

and this is the handler:

```
textChanged(event) {
    var newDesc = document.getElementById('descript').value;
    this.setState({'description':newDesc});
}
```

This works, but it's an incredibly expensive way to have React not do anything. Is there a better/right way to approach this that will just let me edit the textarea? For example, with the input fields in the form, I just use defaultValue instead, but I need this one to be multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks! Lots of good answers. This makes sense now and I've adjusted it appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React, this is called a [controlled-component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Since you're setting your `<textarea>`'s value to `this.state.description`, the `<textarea>` will always reflect this, making the React state the source of truth. As a result you must also handle changes. You may be falling victim to premature optimization, this is generally very fast, and is a best practice. In React, your component rendering should be predicable based on your state and props.

As Arslan mentioned, however, since your handler receives `event` just the same as a normal `onChange` handler, a simpler way to do this is simply to set your state to `event.target.value` rather than grabbing a reference to your `<textarea>` and getting it's value.

Answer (score 6):

The way you are trying is okay. Just need a little tweak. Try this:

```
<textarea 
    id="descript"
    rows="8"
    value={this.state.description} 
    onChange={this.textChanged} 
/>

textChanged(event) {
    this.setState({
        description: event.target.value
    });
}
```

And don't forget to bind the function in your constructor like this:

```
this.textChanged= this.textChanged.bind(this);
```

As you are using it as a controlled component so the state will always be reflected in the textarea's value.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why the `textarea` contents need to be in the `state`?
You can use another variable (or a property passed into the component) instead:

`<textarea id="descript" rows="8" value={description} />`

or

`<textarea id="descript" rows="8" value={this.props.description} />`

Then instead of an `onChange` handler, you read the updated value of the `textarea` when you are ready to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the  as a controlled component, where the value it holds will always be *this.state.description*. You are right that when used this way you will need supply an *onChange* function but you do not need to set an id and use the document API.

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

You do not need to use it as a controlled component. If you don't set the value prop you will be able to type as is. Then when you wish to capture that value you can read the value from the textarea element either by ref or by id.